# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'props.todo' as it is undefined. React

Tags: reactjs

I am creating To do list app in React. It reads the input field correctly from state, but, when I added file, which reads all the information from input and outputs it as a new div with the name of todo item, it shows an error - "TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'props.todo' as it is undefined".

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Container, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import AddForm from './components/AddForm';
import TodoList from './components/TodoList';



function App() {

  const  [todos, addTodos] = useState([]);

  const addTodoHandler = todo => addTodos([...todos, todo]);


  return (
  <Container fluid>
    <Row>
      <h1>Todo list</h1>
      <Col>
        <TodoList todos={todos} /> 
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <AddForm addTodoHandler={addTodoHandler}/>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React from 'react';

const TodoList = (props) => {

    const {name} = props.todo;

    return (
        <div>
            <div>{name} </div>
            <button>Delete</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TodoList;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

class AddForm extends React.Component {

  state = {
    name: "",
  };

  add = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.name === "") {
      alert("Todo cannot be empty");
      return;
    }

    this.props.addTodoHandler(this.state);
    alert(this.state.name)
    this.setState({ name: "" });
  };
render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Add Todo</h2>
      <form onSubmit={this.add}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="todo"
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={(e) => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
        />
        <Button type="submit">Add</Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
};

export default AddForm;
```

Comment: should `const {name} = props.todo;` not be `const {name} = props.todos;`?

Comment: yes, thanks. Now it's working

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments you need to fix the destructuring statement to use the correct prop (todos instead of todo).

But you have an additional problem in that your `<TodoList>` component is not set up to render a list.  You're passing `todos` as an array prop to `<TodoList>` but in `<TodoList>` you're using it as a single object.  You'll need to fix that as well.  If you want a list to be rendered you'll need to iterate over it.  Something like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const TodoList = (props) => {

    const list = props.todos || [];

    return list.map(item => 
        <div>
            <div>{item.name} </div>
            <button>Delete</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TodoList;
```

Note that this also checks for props.todos to be undefined and if so assigns list to be an empty array so that the render has a value and does not crash.